# colour each bar in an R barplot

Tags: r, matrix, bar-chart

I have a matrix which looks like

```
4   1
7   2
4   1
2   3
12  4
```

where the left column specifies the height of each bar in a bar plot and the right column specifies the index of a vector with hex colours. Each bar in the barplot should received the colour which is indexed in the right column. Is there an easy way to do that?

The question is about how to use the right column as an index not directly as a colour in R. The vector with the colours is named colours and if the right column is 1 the colour in hex format (with the #) is stored in colours[1] which is #ADCD00

Answer (score 0):

```
# your data
m <- read.table(text="4   1
7   2
4   1
2   3
12  4", header=FALSE)

# plot
barplot(m[,1], col=m[,2])
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the colors used in the barplot are derived from `palette()`. You can use different colors by specifying an alternative vector of colours. Here are some examples:

```
library("colourlovers")
p <- clpalettes()
layout(matrix(1:4, nrow=2))
for(i in 1:4) barplot(m[,1], col = swatch(p[[i]])[[1]][m[,2]])
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: but m[,2] only contains the index...not the colour the colours are saved in a vector called colours so if m[,2] is 1 the colour (in hex format) is stored in colours[1]. Could you show how to do that?

Comment: thanks for the additional colours but I just dont knwo how to do the part with the indexing in the colours vector as mentioned in the previous comment. Would be very grateful fo rhelp

Comment: @Hein The additional color examples show you this. You can specify `col = colors[m[,2]]`, which will use the second column of your data as indices for the `colors` vector.